# Lua error for wireshark attempt to index global 'bit' (a function value)

Tags: permissions, lua, websocket

I'm getting this error:

```
Here the packet is not properly decoding on wireshark version 4.0.6
Attached is the packet
Frame 3457: 140 bytes on wire (1120 bits), 140 bytes captured (1120 bits) on interface lo, id 1
Ethernet II, Src: 00:00:00_00:00:00 (00:00:00:00:00:00), Dst: 00:00:00_00:00:00 (00:00:00:00:00:00)
Internet Protocol Version 4, Src: 10.5.12.56, Dst: 10.5.12.56
Transmission Control Protocol, Src Port: 58498, Dst Port: 4444, Seq: 1169, Ack: 1229, Len: 74
Transport Layer Security
WebSocket
Building Automation and Control Network LPDU
Lua Error: /root/.local/lib/wireshark/plugins/4.0/bsc.lua:321: attempt to index global 'bit' (a function value)
```